# Is there a Python function for correcting the following TypeError?

Tags: python, pandas

I run this code:

```
window_size = 100
N = data_train.size
std_avg_pred = []
std_avg_x = []
errors_mse = []
for pred_price in range(window_size, N):
  if pred_price >= N:
    date = apple_data.datetime.strptime(k, '%Y-%m-%d').date() + apple_data.timedelta(days = 1)
  else:
    date = apple_data.loc[pred_price, 'Date']
```

and get the following TypeError:

```
TypeError: cannot do index indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'> with these indexers [100] of <class 'int'>
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Please include the _full_ error message.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you try to go to index 100 in this line:

```
date = apple_data.loc[pred_price, 'Date']
```

but the index of apple_data dataframe is not of *int* type (probably it is timestamp).